# Ubuntu 14.04 Atheros AR922X [168c:0029] Wifi PCI memory region reserve error

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, atheros, ath9k

I've been struggling with this for a while. Can't make my PCI Wifi card work on a desktop with Ubuntu 14.04. I'm attaching the wireless-info.txt by the 'wireless-info' script. Please note the first line of the dmesg section, "ath9k 0000:05:00.0: PCI memory region reserve error". Seems like a problem with the driver? Googled this like crazy to no avail. Does anyone know how to fix this? I need to stay on 14.04 because I'm running software that depends on this exact version.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Feb 2016 16:26 CET +0100

Booted last: 04 Feb 2016 16:19 CET +0100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-43-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 15:44:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /home/pszoldan/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:859e]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR922X Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0029] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:2093]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1267:0210 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc LG Optical Mouse 3D-310
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

ath9k                 147456  0
ath9k_common           32768  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              458752  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              708608  1 ath9k
cfg80211              524288  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               24576  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  0
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
video                  20480  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>
          inet addr:192.168.2.53  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:46029 (46.0 KB)  TX bytes:31398 (31.3 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

        NetworkManager

Running:

root       799     1  0 16:19 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.2.53
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.2.254

    DNS:             192.168.2.254

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SwGVpKKDek
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Budapest (based on set time zone)

country 00:
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
        (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
        (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
        (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     41D979FB10C5D31B45EF47A
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:9B:1E:7E:98:41:E9:CF:EF:25:6B:70:AB:21:05:62:DA:B1:EF:68
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     8836292C9539A29CB162A5D
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:9B:1E:7E:98:41:E9:CF:EF:25:6B:70:AB:21:05:62:DA:B1:EF:68
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     C1A24C37619ED65AB1240B9
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:9B:1E:7E:98:41:E9:CF:EF:25:6B:70:AB:21:05:62:DA:B1:EF:68
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     D89F916A5E804AF040C4D29
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:9B:1E:7E:98:41:E9:CF:EF:25:6B:70:AB:21:05:62:DA:B1:EF:68
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-43-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     47672A7084D52DFBE51E2D2
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:9B:1E:7E:98:41:E9:CF:EF:25:6B:70:AB:21:05:62:DA:B1:EF:68
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-43-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F28307769349A31F4B24FC2
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:9B:1E:7E:98:41:E9:CF:EF:25:6B:70:AB:21:05:62:DA:B1:EF:68
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    1.761113] ath9k 0000:05:00.0: PCI memory region reserve error
[    2.204567] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[    2.204592] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    5.268430] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
[    5.268438] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```